# PHP Secured Soap connection failure

Tags: php, soap, ssl-certificate

For a customer we're making a (secured) Soap connection with a Dutch asbestos governmental API in PHP (Laravel in our case) but we are struggling with setting it up.

We've received a guide on how to create the required SSL certificate files, mailed them to the company that provides the API, tested the `.wsdl` file with SSL(with the `.pfx` file) in SoapUI and everything works perfectly.

But when we use it in PHP's `SoapClient`, an Exception is thrown mentioning:

"Could not connect to host"

Here's our code:

```
$wsdl = resource_path("wsdl/testing/portal_1_1.wsdl");

/**
* @see https://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.construct.php
*/
$options = [
'location'       => 'https://acceptatie.tws-esb.rws.nl/lavs-koppelvlak-bacc',
'local_cert'     => resource_path("certs" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "vdm-lavs.pem"),
'passphrase'     => 'Pr0v!de',
'cache_wsdl'     => "WSDL_CACHE_NONE",
'trace'          => true,
'exceptions'     => true,
'soap_version'   => SOAP_1_1,
'stream_context' => stream_context_create([
    'ssl' => [
        'verify_peer'       => false,
        'verify_peer_name'  => false,
    ],
])
];

$soapClient = new \SoapClient($wsdl, $options);
$result = $soapClient->__soapCall('statusOpvraging', []);
```

What I've checked so far is :

1. Adding `allow_self_signed` to the ssl configuration
2. Since the SoapUI uses the `.pfx` certificate and the `local_cert` in SoapClient in PHP does not work with `.pfx` but `.pem`, we tried both
3. We tried it in Postman as a regular HTTP call and it works fine
4. We've tried in an old PHP 5.6 and Laravel 5.3.0 and a new fresh PHP 8.0 with Laravel 8.68.1 configuration, both result in the same error.

Does anybody have any suggestion?